# Kendo Angular Combobox breaks click event

Tags: html, css, angular, combobox, kendo-ui

We have had a Kendo Angular implementation in place for several years now. We recently updated Kendo and Angular and we found that a click event we placed on a  is now broken.

We have an outer div which contains our combobox and another div with an icon containing a click event that is broken. See the screenshot with the red arrow pointing to the broken div icon.

[image: Broken Combobox and div]

Below is the HTML and the css governing the div.

```
<div *ngIf="values.length < maxCardinality"
     class="editor-row">
    <kendo-combobox #selectBox
                    [data]="connectionCandidates$ | async"
                    [textField]="'_id'"
                    [valueField]="'name'"
                    [filterable]="true"
                    [placeholder]="'Search...'"
                    (selectionChange)="handleComboBoxValueChange($event)"
                    (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"
                    class="reference-combobox">
        <ng-template *ngIf="resultCount >= 50" kendoComboBoxNoDataTemplate>
            <span i18n>50+ partial matches. Type more.</span>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template *ngIf="resultCount == 0" kendoComboBoxNoDataTemplate>
            <span i18n>No results found.</span>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem>
            <span class="row">
                <div *ngIf="hasConnectionTo(dataItem)"
                     class="checkmark"></div>
                <span class="item"
                      [ngClass]="{
                          connected: hasConnectionTo(dataItem)
                      }">
                    {{ dataItem.name }}
                </span>
            </span>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-combobox>
    <div
        class="picker-button"
        *ngIf="values.length < maxCardinality"
        (click)="handleClickReferencePicker($event)"></div>
</div>
```

The Div at the end of this with the class "picker-button" is the broken click event.

CSS for the picker-button

```
.picker-button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
        right: 32px;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        outline: none;
        display: flex;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 24px;
        height: 20px;
        background-size: 20px 20px;
        background: url($assets-dir + '/picker_multiple_blue.svg') 3px 2px no-repeat transparent;

        &.disabled {
            background: url($assets-dir + '/picker_multiple_grey.svg') 3px 2px no-repeat transparent;
        }
    }
```

I omitted the rest of the CSS file as I don't think its relevant.

I have moved the div outside of the div containing the combobox and I can get the click event to work. I have tinkered with removing some CSS elements as an experiment to no avail. Its worth nothing this is all within a kendo grid cell. Anyone that can toss any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding a z-index: 2; to the picker-button class. The Combobox updates added a z-index of 1 causing it to overwrite our click event.